# How to get coffeescript to compile on Heroku?

Tags: javascript, heroku, compilation, coffeescript

I'm using Rails 3.2 and have this as a Gemfile:

```
gem 'rails', '3.2.11'

group :development do
  gem 'sqlite3', '1.3.5'
  gem 'rspec-rails', '2.11.0'
end

group :assets do
  gem 'sass-rails',   '3.2.5'
  gem 'coffee-rails', '3.2.2'
  gem 'uglifier', '1.2.3'
end

gem 'jquery-rails', '2.0.2'
gem 'coffee-script'

group :test do
  gem 'capybara', '1.1.2'
end

group :production do
  gem 'pg', '0.12.2'
  gem 'therubyracer-heroku', '~> 0.8.1.pre3'
end
```

My webapp runs fine on localhost, but it's not working on Heroku because of a coffeescript file. I'm on Heroku Cedar if that helps in any way. I looked at the source in the Heroku webapp, and it doesn't look like my cofeescript was compiled into the minified javascript that Heroku does. How do I get that coffeescript to compile on Heroku? What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We'd need to know a lot more about your application to check every possibility.

A good place to start to would be `rake assets:precompile` and ensure you can run that locally.  It's the command Heroku is going to run - or should if things are set up properly.

To get farther, I suggest you read up on the asset pipeline on Heroku and make sure you are "crossing your t's and dotting your i's"

- http://guides.rubyonrails.org/asset_pipeline.html
- https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/rails3x-asset-pipeline-cedar

If you still have trouble, you may be able to edit this question with more specific information.

Answer (score 0):

On Heroku's Cedar, there's no need for therubyracer-heroku to be included in the Gemfile. Checking the application.js in my source, I found that the coffeescript did get compiled into javascript. The problem was that I had some other files that my coffeescript depended on stored in app/assets/libs. I don't think Heroku went that deep, so I believe that the javascripts were not all loaded. I did not need to run a `rake assets:precompile` neither. Here is the Gemfile that works:

```
source 'https://rubygems.org'

gem 'rails', '3.2.11'

group :development do
  gem 'sqlite3', '1.3.5'
  gem 'rspec-rails', '2.11.0'
end

# Gems used only for assets and not required
# in production environments by default.
group :assets do
  gem 'sass-rails',   '3.2.5'
  gem 'coffee-rails', '3.2.2'
  gem 'uglifier', '1.2.3'
end

gem 'jquery-rails', '2.0.2'

group :test do
    gem 'capybara', '1.1.2'
end

group :production do
  gem 'pg', '0.12.2'
end
```